# Return true or false using map arrays

Tags: javascript, typescript

I need to return a boolean value to assign to my form's checkboxes by checking if the value exists in the array.

For this I've been trying to use `.map()` by traversing a list of ID's and checking if this id exists within that list by returning an array of Boolean values.

```
const arrayOne = ['id1', 'id2', 'id3', 'id4', 'id5'];
const arrayTwo = ['id4'];
const booleanValues = [false, false, false, true, false]; // expected outcome
```

How to check if the id exists in another array returning boolean values using `.map()` in a simplified and readable way?

Comment: I have already tried some forms, but none that was legible of easy understanding ... I know how easy it is but I am not able to create something simple with readability.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd just use `includes` to see if the value of `arr` is present in `checkVals`:

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
var checkVals = [2];
    
var results = arr.map(n => checkVals.includes(n));
    
console.log(results);
// [false, true, false]
```

Instead of using an array for `checkVals`, you could also use a Set for better performance. That's likely not necessary here though.